# Which is the best way to create a multiple Form in MVC (Separate pages or partial views in a navtab ) for customer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Your Product</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" aria-controls="second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">AMC</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Third" aria-controls="Third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Quotation</a></li>        
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Fifth" aria-controls="Fifth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
```

while designing it must look user friendly, simple....
above code which i am using will be good

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Third">
            <br />
            @Html.Partial("Quotation")

        </div>
```

like this or any suggestion